# Extract dates from all years less than mm-dd in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to pull some data from a Postgres database to implement a birthday reminder system, but I am having a little trouble in getting my query to work. Basically, I want to pull all of the records whose birthday field falls within a certain one-month span. I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT *
ALL persons
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH from birthday) >= 9
AND EXTRACT(DAY from birthday) >= 15
INTERSECT
SELECT *
ALL persons
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH from birthday) <= 10
AND EXTRACT(DAY from birthday) <= 15
```

The first portion of the query (before the `INTERSECT`) seems to be working as I would like, but the second portion is excluding dates in *any* month before the 15th. For instance, if there was a birthday on 9/20, the first portion would include it but the second portion would exclude it since it is after the 15th day (even though it still falls before 10/15). Any ideas how to remedy this?

Comment: It's generally a good idea to mention your PostgreSQL version with posts. Some features, like writable CTEs, window functions, etc, are only available in newer versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM persons
WHERE
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM age(CURRENT_DATE, birthday)) = 11; -- less than one month the next birthday
```

edit: bug fixed

Comment: Nice; I'd managed to miss `age` but it looks extremely handy. In fact, it's time to go and rewrite a few reports. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! That's nice and concise. I've mainly worked with MySQL in the past, so I am still getting used to Postgres.

Answer (score 2):

This query output persons with less than a month to birthday:

```
select * from persons where EXTRACT(MONTH FROM age(birthday))=0
```

if you want to output birthdays with month before and AFTER:

```
select * from persons where EXTRACT(MONTH FROM age(birthday)) in (0,11)
```

Comment: I like the `age` trick, that's clever. The queries aren't well formed, though; you're missing a `WHERE` clause. Did you test it?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Somehow I'd managed to miss ever seeing SQLFiddle; that's *cool* when dealing with different DBs or old versions. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

What about
select * from persons where birthday between '2012-09-15' and '2012-10-15'

Comment: These people are not born yet, so you're not sure when they will have their birthday.